# Split me in two; I make you excavate

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> Split me in two
>   I make you excavate
>   Take me as one
>   I enumerate

Comment: You know, in this world there's two kinds of people, my friend. Those who enumerate and those who excavate. You excavate.

Comment: Well... Is that a good thing, @Randal'Thor :)?

Comment: *ahem* ```s/excavate/appreciate/```

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac [if you didn't get the reference :-)](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Good,_the_Bad_and_the_Ugly)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are

> a **DIGIT**.

Split me in two
I make you excavate

> Split the word into two to make DIG IT, which could be said to someone to make them excavate something.

Take me as one
I enumerate

> Digits are used to express numbers and can also refer to fingers, which you can count with.

Comment: Nice answer. I dig it, man.